# jQuery slide down panel open/close

Tags: jquery

I have setup 3 slide down panels features on my website, my issue is you can click and expand all 3 at the same time and they overlap and look messy, is there a way I can have one open at a time so the others automatically close when another is opened.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".topLink01").click(function () {
 $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
 $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
 return false;
});


 $(".topLink02").click(function () {
 $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
 $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
 return false;
});


 $(".topLink03").click(function () {
 $("#panel3").slideToggle("slow");
 $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
 return false;
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="topLink topLink01">BUTTON<</a>

<a href="#" class="topLink topLink02">BUTTON</a>

<a href="#" class="topLink topLink03">BUTTON</a>

<div id="panel1">
CONTENT
</div>

<div id="panel2">
CONTENT
</div>

<div id="panel3">
CONTENT>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#panel1{ position:absolute; background: #0e5faf; display: none; right:0; top:36px; width: 250px; z-index:999; line-height: 18px; padding:15px; }

#panel2{ position:absolute; background: #0e5faf; display: none; right:0; top:36px; width: 250px; z-index:999; line-height: 18px; padding:15px; }

#panel3{ position:absolute; background: #0e5faf; display: none; right:0; top:36px; width: 250px; z-index:999; line-height: 18px; padding:15px; }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already accepted an answer however your approach is not very efficient. I'll leave this here, perhaps it will help you.

CSS:

```
    .toggles{display:none}
```

HTML:

```
    <a href="" class="topLink" data-target="t1">BUTTON</a>
    <a href="" class="topLink" data-target='t2'>BUTTON</a>
    <a href="" class="topLink" data-target='t3'>BUTTON</a>
    <div class="toggles" data-target='t1'>CONTENT1</div>
    <div class="toggles" data-target='t2'>CONTENT2</div>
    <div class="toggles" data-target='t3'>CONTENT3</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".topLink").on('click', function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var e = $(this); //writing $(this) every time is bad
                t = $("div[data-target='"+e.attr('data-target')+"']"); //same as above

            if(e.hasClass('active')){ 
                //remove from this
                e.removeClass("active");
                //close box    
                t.slideUp("slow");
            } else { //toggle menu when clicking on some other link
                //remove from everywhere
                $(".topLink").removeClass('active');
                //slide every box up
                $('.toggles').slideUp("slow");
                //add to this only
                e.addClass('active'); 
                //slide associated box down
                t.slideDown("slow");
            }
        });     
    });
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujw1evk1/1/) just in case you look over it. Of course this code can be improved upon as well.

Comment: Thanks this appears to be a better solution, ill incorporate it into my project soon and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hey, sorry to bug you again but I have had a request to add in a close button/text, is there a way to make a basic link trigger "e.removeClass("active");"

Comment: Yes there is, though i'm not sure what your intended functionality is. See the fiddle (i've updated it).

Comment: Again thanks for your help! You need an award or something :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var opened = $(".panel");
$(".topLink01").click(function () {
opened.slideToggle("slow");
$(".active").toggleClass("active");
 $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
opened = $("#panel1");
 $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
 return false;
});


 $(".topLink02").click(function () {
opened.slideToggle("slow");
$(".active").toggleClass("active");
 $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
opened = $("#panel2");
 $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
 return false;
});


 $(".topLink03").click(function () {
opened.slideToggle("slow");
$(".active").toggleClass("active");
 $("#panel3").slideToggle("slow");
opened = $("#panel3");
 $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
 return false;
});

});
</script>
<a href="#" class="topLink topLink01">BUTTON<</a>

<a href="#" class="topLink topLink02">BUTTON</a>

<a href="#" class="topLink topLink03">BUTTON</a>

<div id="panel1" class="panel">
CONTENT
</div>

<div id="panel2" class="panel">
CONTENT
</div>

<div id="panel3" class="panel">
CONTENT>
</div>
```

Comment: This works how I require but I am having a couple of issues, it messes up the active class, now all or some keep the active class, I only want the open slide to have the active class, also before if you clicked on the button it would close the panel, now it closes and re-opens, I don't mind if I have to add a close button.